# How can I turn an int into three bytes in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift

I am trying to convert an `int` into three `bytes` representing that `int` (big endian).

I'm sure it has something to do with bit-wise and and bit shifting.  But I have no idea how to go about doing it.

For example:

```
int myInt;

// some code

byte b1, b2 , b3; // b1 is most significant, then b2 then b3.
```

*Note, I am aware that an int is 4 bytes and the three bytes have a chance of over/underflowing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the least significant byte:

```
b3 = myInt & 0xFF;
```

The 2nd least significant byte:

```
b2 = (myInt >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

And the 3rd least significant byte:

```
b1 = (myInt >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

**Explanation:**

Bitwise ANDing a value with 0xFF (11111111 in binary) will return the least significant 8 bits (bits 0 to 7) in that number. Shifting the number to the right 8 times puts bits 8 to 15 into bit positions 0 to 7 so ANDing with 0xFF will return the second byte. Similarly, shifting the number to the right 16 times puts bits 16 to 23 into bit positions 0 to 7 so ANDing with 0xFF returns the 3rd byte.

Answer (score 3):

```
byte b1 = (myint >> 16) & 0xff;
byte b2 = (myint >> 8) & 0xff;
byte b3 = myint & 0xff;
```

I am unsure how this holfds in java though, i aam not a java dev

Comment: Actually you need an explicit cast from int to byte, and then the `& 0xff` is unnecessary (and bytes are signed, unlike C#).

Answer (score 2):

An int doesn't fit into 3 bytes.  However, assuming that you know these particular ones do:

```
   byte b1 = (myInt & 0xff);
   myInt >>= 8;
   byte b2 = (myInt & 0xff);
   myInt >>= 8;
   byte b3 = (myInt & 0xff);
```

Comment: You've got the most/least significant order reversed.

Comment: There's no need to modify myInt unnecessarily, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

In Java

```
int myInt = 1;
byte b1,b2,b3;
b3 = (byte)(myInt & 0xFF);
b2 = (byte)((myInt >> 8) & 0xFF);
b1 = (byte)((myInt >> 16) & 0xFF);
System.out.println(b1+" "+b2+" "+b3);
```

outputs **0 0 1**

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Jeremy is correct in case of positive integer value. If the conversion should be correct for negative values, it is little more complicated due to two's-complement format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The trick is to remove the gap between the interesting bits (the less significant bits) and the 'sign' bit. One easy method is multiplication of the number.

```
    int myIntMultiplied = myInt * 256;

    byte b1, b2, b3;

    b3 = (byte) ((myIntMultiplied >> 8) & 0xFF);
    b2 = (byte) ((myIntMultiplied >> 16) & 0xFF);
    b1 = (byte) ((myIntMultiplied >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

This will end up with correct two's-complement format for negative values.

PS: You can check and compare binary representation this way:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(myInt);
Integer.toBinaryString(myIntMultiplied );
```